# Why is there no analytic solution for logistic regression?

Tags: logistic

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [When is logistic regression solved in closed form?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/949/when-is-logistic-regression-solved-in-closed-form)

Why is there no analytic solution for logistic regression?
I was trying to derive a solution similar to the normal equations of linear regression, and I am not sure where it goes wrong.
Please provide a mathematical proof.