# Calculate coefficients in a ordinal logistic regression with R

Tags: regression, regression-coefficients, ordered-logit

Following the question about [manually fitting logistic regression](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/81000/calculate-coefficients-in-a-logistic-regression-with-r), can someone provide the same 'manual' way to fit a ordinal logistic regression with ordered categorical response?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's assume you have an ordinal response with 4 categories, so you want to estimate 3 parameters which will be the thresholds of the latent continuous response.

First think the log-likelihood function for a given set of $\mathbf{\theta}$ parameters you want to estimate.

```r
ll.ord.log <- function(theta, x, y){
    t1    <- theta[1]
    t2    <- theta[2]
    t3    <- theta[3]
    b     <- matrix(theta[4:5])
    one   <- cbind(log( 1/(1+exp(x%*%b-t1)) - 0 ), y)
    two   <- cbind(log( 1/(1+exp(x%*%b-t2)) - 1/(1+exp(x%*%b-t1)) ), y)
    three <- cbind(log( 1/(1+exp(x%*%b-t3)) - 1/(1+exp(x%*%b-t2)) ), y)
    four  <- cbind(log( 1                   - 1/(1+exp(x%*%b-t3)) ), y)

    ll <- sum(one[,1][one[,2]==1]) + 
          sum(two[,1][two[,2]==2]) + 
          sum(three[,1][three[,2]==3]) + 
          sum(four[,1][four[,2]==4])
    -ll
  }
```

Then set some initial values for the optimization and some constrains. Thus, we use the `constrOptim` function which enables us to perform optimization given some constrains of the estimated parameters, since the thresholds need to be ordered.

```r
theta0 <- c(-2,1,4,1,-1)
ui     =  rbind(c(-1,1,0,0,0), c(0,-1,1,0,0), c(-1,0,1,0,0))
ci     =  c(.1,.1,.1)
```

Then, you can use the function from `R` to estimate the maximum likelihood and the estimates at this value.

```r
constrOptim(theta0, ll.ord.log, NULL, x=x, y=y, ui=ui, ci=ci)
```