# Is gradient descent the only way to find the weights in logistic regression?

Tags: regression, logistic, optimization, gradient-descent

This post: [When is logistic regression solved in closed form?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/949/when-is-logistic-regression-solved-in-closed-form) describes that we must use nonlinear optimization methods to find the parameter estimates for logistic regression models. Does gradient descent count as one of these methods? I have not heard of gradient descent described as a nonlinear optimization method. And what other "nonlinear optimization" methods are there for calculating the weights in this case?

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_optimization#Computational_optimization_techniques

Answer (score 0):

A logistic regression is a neural network with no hidden layers. Consequently, any method used for calculating the weights in a neural network is fair game for a logistic regression.

Comment: The only method I know to calculate weights in a neural network is gradient descent, so is that our only option?